# .Net Maui cant compile a fresh macos project

Tags: c#, .net, macos, maui

I wanted to play a little with .Net Maui. So, I just used the maui-check tool to install the latest version of .Net Maui on my Mac (OSX 11.4). Then I created a blank macos project using the dotnet tool:

```
dotnet new macos
```

Trying to compile this blank new project I receive the following error:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.100-preview.5.21302.13/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.ILLink.targets(181,5): error NETSDK1102: Optimizing assemblies for size is not supported for the selected publish configuration. Please ensure that you are publishing a self-contained app.
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Best regards...

Comment: Are you building in debug or release?

Comment: You could ask in here https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues

Comment: The error appears both with Release and Debug configuration.

Comment: I opened an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1764

Answer (score 0):

MAUI is not offical support for macOS yet as verion of 17.3 Visual studio.
the most important is **Pre-requisites** your mac have to run **latest Xcode 13**
source: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/macOS-Install